Tax law and its capacity to change society
I am currently exploring the intersection of tax law and politics.

How has tax law influenced societal change in recent years?

I am particularly interested in what mechanisms or tools enable tax law to effect such changes.

This is way too broad

Welcome to [politics.se]. Please check the help center and the FAQs. More to the point, you should be asking questions specific enough that they can have one right answer of a reasonable length. As it stands now, either you require an answer of several volumes in print, of lid of answer of different examples. You may edit your question so that it fits these guidelines.

I would search that topic with a search engine, read a couple of texts and then come back with more specific questions. In general, taxes redistribute money and personnel decisions are made in order to maximize something including financial freedom for example. Taxes can shift the position of that maximum.
